autodoc_pydantic: Show fields from parent model if parent model and child are in different files
In this question exists an answer how to reach to display parents attributes in child class. However it doesn't work for me, because my parent and child class are in different files:
.. currentmodule:: module.child_bar

.. autopydantic_model:: Bar
    :inherited-members: Foo
    :member-order: bysource
    :model-show-field-summary: false
    :field-show-constraints: false

when my parent class is in module.parent_foo
I can duplicate docstrings or write decorator that adds parents docstring to child class, but I want more flexible solution

The problem was that my classes are inherited from pydantic class, and in :inherited-members: I need to pass class which attributes I do not want to display, therefore I need to pass
:inherited-members: BaseModel

and everything displays correctly
